# How do I deploy an Amazon S3 console app with IAM security

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Using the Visual Studio project template proved by the Amazon [AWS SDK 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V3/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html) (windows) I have created a simple AWS Console app (c#) for uploading assets to Amazon S3.

For security I am using the [Amazon recommended IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html). This works fine.

Now I want a colleague to use my new console app but, of course, he does not have my IAM credentials as these are not present in the `App.config` file. Consequently he receives a security error when he runs my console app.

How do I distribute my console app with IAM security so my colleague can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to do the following:

1. Set the `AWSProfileName` key in your App.config to the value you have set up in the aws console
2. Set the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to the values you have in the aws console